# Make a stub for Include in C# and Entity Framework (Moq,unit testing)?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, moq

Currently I use the packages `Moq` and `EntityFrameworkCoreMock` for unit tests in .NET 6.0. Since I haven't found a method stub for include yet, I can't test code with include statements (I also tried several other packages that mock DbSet, but none has worked with include).

```
// example
User u = await context.Users
                      .Include(i => i.Notifications)
                      .Where(s => string.Equals(s.UserId, "user123"))
                      .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        
// u.Notifications = null
```

I also tried to use the following method, that I can mock then, but this only works for one include statement and not when I have `.Include(..).ThenInclude(..)`

```
public static System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TSource> FirstOrDefaultAsyncWithInclude<TSource, TProperty> (this System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource> source, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> path) where TSource : class 
{
    return source.Include(path).FirstOrDefaultAsync(); 
}
```

I don't want to use the In-Memory database provider, because I write unit tests and because of the performance.

Does anyone know a solution to the problem? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you want encapsulate the EF layer, maybe the repository pattern can help you.

Comment: @vernou Thanks for your suggestion. I think in my case this would drastically reduce the flexibility and is therefore not an option for me.

Comment: What do you want test?

Comment: What means _"don't work for `.Include(..).ThenInclude(..)`"_ ? Are not implemented? Or just doesn't work?

Comment: @vernou the business logic

Comment: @daniherrera i have no clue how i could implement this :(